# Maven: Updated struts version in pom and now i'm getting a weird error

Tags: java, struts2, maven-3

I updated a project that was using struts 2.2.3.1 to the 2.3.1.2 in the pom.xml file. After running maven it picked up the jar from the repo and all that and built the package just fine. But, when I run the webapp I am getting this error:

> 2012-04-26 13:42:06,300 ERROR org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.error:38 - Dispatcher initialization faile Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/Library/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/idmadmin/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72.....

I was thinking that maybe the old one was still stuck in the classpath but I don't see it.

Comment: The tail end of that error seems to point to a specific line of struts-default.xml.  Perhaps that line was valid in the former version, but not the latter?  Posting that file's contents may help potential answerers.

Comment: What's the rest of the trace? Anything else on startup at DEBUG logging with devMode on?

Comment: Recently I had a similar error it was due to cutting and pasting a non visible character. Make sure you are using
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd"> validate the xml file in your IDE, before deployment. If the XML visually looks valid, check for hidden characters (highlight all shift-tab several times to flatten the structure, then check each line end to make sure there are no blanks, then auto format back to proper nesting). Finally if validation fails, remove blocks to find the error.